# String concat in Google Closure stylesheets?

Tags: css, google-closure, google-closure-stylesheet

I simply have the code

```
@def WIDTH 50 // will be reused
// ...
width: @def WIDTH px // incorrect space between
```

I believe CSS doesn't allow the space between # and px which makes this code wrong. But I haven't found a string concat function. Is there a way to do this?

I'm aware I can @def WIDTH to be 50px, that will break its reuse.

Answer (score 2):

A correct Closure solution to this problem is to `mult` by the unit.

```
width: mult(1px, WIDTH);
```